# Rotate a triangle continuously

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I have a `float[] newCoords` variable that has a **size of 9**. The first 3 entries represent one vertex, the next 3 represent the second vertex and the last 3 represent the last vertex.

I have some code that is supposed to rotate a triangle anywhere in space when I feed it the coordinates. It looks like this:

```
float s = (float) Math.sin(0.5);
float c = (float) Math.cos(0.5);

float[] centroid = getCentroid(newCoords);

newCoords[0] -= centroid[0];
newCoords[1] -= centroid[1];
newCoords[3] -= centroid[0];
newCoords[4] -= centroid[1];
newCoords[6] -= centroid[0];
newCoords[7] -= centroid[1];

newCoords[0] = (newCoords[0] * c) - (newCoords[1] * s);
newCoords[1] = (newCoords[0] * s) + (newCoords[1] * c);

newCoords[3] = (newCoords[3] * c) - (newCoords[4] * s);
newCoords[4] = (newCoords[3] * s) + (newCoords[4] * c);

newCoords[6] = (newCoords[6] * c) - (newCoords[7] * s);
newCoords[7] = (newCoords[6] * s) + (newCoords[7] * c);

newCoords[0] += centroid[0];
newCoords[1] += centroid[1];
newCoords[3] += centroid[0];
newCoords[4] += centroid[1];
newCoords[6] += centroid[0];
newCoords[7] += centroid[1];
```

The problem is, its not rotating it properly, the triangles are spinning and getting smaller and smaller until they disappear for some reason, can anyone see why this is happening?

EDIT: whoops, almost forgot, here is my `getCentroid()` method.

```
private float[] getCentroid(float[] p1) {
    float[] newCoords = new float[] {(p1[0] + p1[3] + p1[6]) / 3.0f,
                                     (p1[1] + p1[4] + p1[7]) / 3.0f, 0};
    return newCoords;
}
```

Comment: This looks like Java to me...

Comment: @leemes my bad. Its 1 am here xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems with your code. Both are fixed with a little change.

1. You try to apply a rotation operation, taking X and Y coordinates as input and having the new X and Y as output. For every vertex you rotate, you have two lines of code: the first computes the X, the second the Y coordinate. But when computing the Y coordinate, you use the **already rotated** X coordinate! That's wrong.
2. There is also a **numerical problem**. You reuse the old values again and again, resulting in a **chain of rotation computations** a value makes though, so the numerical errors sum up. Never rely on such computations to work as expected. Instead, you should work with the *original* values and increase the angle in each frame. This makes sure that each value only participated in a **single rotation computation**.

For fixing both problems, keep the original coordinates somewhere in your code, I call them `coords`, and rewrite the code such that you take that array as input (keep `newCoords` as the output). Increase the rotation angle in each frame to achieve a rotation animation.

This fixes both problems because you get rid of that chain and also you have different arrays for input and output in your rotation function.

Pseudo-code:

```
// initial:
angle = 0.0;
coords = (initial coordinates)

// per frame:
angle += 0.5;
newCoords = rotate(coords, angle);
draw(newCoords);
```

Also, please note that `0.5` is a large angle if you want to rotate by that angle frame by frame. The math functions expect angle in radians (not degrees), so you might want to use a lower value depending on what you want to visualize in particular.

You might wonder why I reuse the old angle in each frame, as according to the above mentioned problem 2., it should introduce numerical problems, since it's also a chain of computations. That's not a problem with the rotation angle, as a simple summation doesn't show such bad numerical errors you experience with applying rotations. Yet it has some problems, but they only show up at very long running times when the angle reaches some billions. The reason why such a summation in general is not that bad is because you're changing the variable in the same direction in each frame as well as a slightly off rotation angle isn't noticed very much by the user.

Comment: I am rotating by a constant 0.2 radians every 100 milliseconds. The rotate method is just not rotating it properly, I dont know why its decreasing the size of the triangle though.

Comment: @Clay Wait, there is another problem with your code which is probably the main reason. Let me fix that.

Comment: @Clay Ok now please look at my answer again, point 1. is very important. The change I suggest should fix both problems.

Comment: Please do not apply fixes suggested in answers in your original question. That's because that makes my answer invalid (it doesn't match the question anymore). I'll revert your edit of the question. The problem in your current code is that you have `p1, p2, p2` (instead of `p1, p2, p3`) in the formulas for the new values. Also, you only fixed the problem 1 I mentioned, not problem 2 (you still have that chain of computations).

Comment: Oh my god, how did I not see that p1 p2 p2... Thank you so much it's working now.

Comment: Umm, just as a side question if you'd like to answer. My screen is 720x1280. But the coordinate system is just -1 to 1. So when the triangle is rotating, it is being stretch in the y more than in the x. Do you know how I can rectify this? Or should I just post another question.

Comment: I think I have to convert to 720x1280 coordinates, rotate it there, and then scale it back to -1 to 1 coordinate system right?

Comment: That has to do with how you project from 3D world space to the screen space. In particular the way you set up the *projection matrix*. There you should set the aspect ratio of your screen, which should be `(float)width / (float)height`.

Comment: But yes, please post another question for this if this simple hint isn't enough to find it out by yourself. In that question, you should in particular show / explain how you initialize OpenGL (usually you set some matrices before rendering points), and if you use any shader programs.

Comment: Ok, I followed this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/projection.html on projection matrices and the triangles are equilateral now. Thanks, no need for another question :)